# No correlation between the XIB file and the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

sorry if it might be a newbie question.

My xib file and my simulator doesnt match:

[image]

But the simulator shows:

[image]

1.How do i fix it? im using 3.5 inch display on both

2.If my view wont fit in the screen ,s s it good practice to put the view in a scrollview so it would match both 3.5 inch and 4 inch ?

EDIT:

I do not have a scrollview.I just asked for general knowledge.
The coordinates are not given programatically. The whole interface is build through Interface Builder.

If i change the view display to "Retina 4-inch full display" and move the labels/textfields view lil bit lower thats what i get:

[image]

My project contains a nav controller with a tableView as its rootVC, and the VC that is shows here as the second one. I didn't changed any of the coordinates in the TableVC nor this VC programatically.

Comment: Probably mostly you're seeing the differences between iOS 6 and iOS 7.  You must somehow make specific adaptations for the difference.  There's probably a way to semi-automagically do this in the screen designer, but I've never attempted that, since most of our stuff is manual layout.

Comment: I think you have to do this yourself. If you would use Auto Layout you could use the topLayoutGuide. But with the old layout system you have to shift and shrink the view in `viewWillAppear:`, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You might have given the coordinates programatically so pls post you code to or try to hide the navigation bar

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and if the coordinates are posted programmatically after implementing on XIB's you must check that via breakpoints and correct them

Comment: Hey, i"v edited the post. plus why should i hide the navigation controller ?

Comment: you just remove this scroll view even if you want to support both the iphone 5 and other versions that i mean 3.5 or 4 inches you can still do by implementing a check for the screen and if you condition is satisfied you can put your textfields and labels and specific postion programmitically. i mean check for on screen size that is for 4 inches or 3.5 programmitically and create other with xib without scrollview this might help you

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you already have a scrollview there, which is very good,
But the problem is the scroll view needs to be configured properly,

ONE way to do it is to make sure the scrollview is attached to all sides (you can set it's distance to all sides to zero, using the autolayout widgets), and make sure to set it's content size to what is needs to be (larger won't hurt), in your `ViewDidLoad`

if you provide more details we'd be able to help better.

Comment: Hey, i'v edited the post. I do not have a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution is to play with the "Attributes inspector" in the "Simulated section" section.

That what worked for me:

[image]

Though i'm not sure this is the best way to fix it.